# LibreOffice Calc format page crashes and does not give options for Sheet margins, portrait etc

Tags: libreoffice

Using LibreOffice version 3.6.0.2 under Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS.

Since upgrading to LibreOffice version 3.6, **Format Page** in Calc has limited tabs to choose from.  The tabs available now are *Organiser, Header (right), Header (left), Footer (right)* and *Footer (left)*.  There is no longer a tab for Sheet which gave options for orientation (landscape/portrait), margins, etc.

The Organizer tab indicates the values of these settings, but gives no option to change any of them.

How can I now change to landscape?

Also, when I try to click on a different tab in **Format Page**, LibreOffice crashes.

Comment: This problem has now been fixed.  I used apt-get delete to remove LO, and then apt-get install to re-install, and the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has now been fixed. I used apt-get delete to remove LO, and then apt-get install to re-install, and the problem has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Version 3.6.2.2 (Build ID: da8c1e6) of LibreOffice direct from libreoffice.org.

In my menu bar, I see *File*, *Edit*, *View*, *Insert*, *Format*, *Tools*, *Data*, *Window*, & *Help*.

If I click on *Format*, I see this dropdown (in part):

[image: format]

If I click on `Page...`, I see this:

[image: Page tab]

or this:

[image: organizer-tab]

And no freezes or crashes.

It's possible that your version (3.6.0.2), is significantly different from mine (3.6.2.2). Another (unlikely) *possibility* is that "integration" via `lo-menubar` causes the difference if you're using Unity. Do you have [lo-menubar](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lo-menubar) installed?

Comment: This problem has now been fixed. I used apt-get delete to remove LO, and then apt-get install to re-install, and the problem has gone away.